# What's different between && and & in this case?

Tags: c, binary, bitwise-operators

I create a simple program in c:

```
int y=33, x=45;
y = y && x;
printf("%d\n",y);
y = y & x;
printf("%d\n",y);
```

The output are 1 and 1. But if I use calculator, it show that x and y is 33. Why it become 1?

Comment: I didn't know calculators have logical operators.

Comment: `&&` is a logical operator that evaluates to true (1) or false (0). So after `y = y && x;`, `y` is equal to 1 (because both x and y are non-zero). `&` is a bitwise operator. Both numbers have bit zero set to 1, so the result of `y = y & x;` is also 1.

Comment: @ squeamish ossifrage Thanks for your explanation.... I'm so happy with that although my post is very weird and get -2. Thanks for your help... I appreciate it....!!!

Comment: you are missing the fact that `y` is not 33 when the `y = y & x` is executed.

Comment: Did my answer helped you or do you need more help?

Answer (score 5):

The fist operator `&&` is a logical operator and means:

(Also notice that the `return/result` of the `logical` `AND` operator is always `true` or `false`, it can't be like 24 or so!)

```
true  =  true  && true
false =  false && true
false =  true  && false
false =  false && false
```

So in your case `y` gets `1` because `33` and `45` are both true! Because if a number is a `non-zero` number it means `true`. Only `0/false` means `false`. Even `-5` means `true`!

The second operator `&` is a bitwise and operator and means in your case this:

```
(y = 1)    0000 0001 & 
(x = 45)   0001 1101 = 
           ---------
(y = 1)    0000 0001
```

Which is equal to `1` and then assgin to `y`

That's why both results are 1!

If you want to calculate `33` & `45` then you have to assign the results to an other variable like this(So that your start values (x, y) don't get overwritten):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    int y = 33, x = 45, z;

    z = y && x;
    printf("%d\n", z); 

    z = y & x;
    printf("%d\n", z);

    return 0;

}
```

Also you could do this calculations without an assignment with these lines of code:

```
printf("%d\n", (y && x));
printf("%d\n", (y & x));
```